# Fixed number of tabs per page in TabLayout

Tags: android, kotlin, tabs, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I am using scrollable TabLayout with a ViewPager.
I want to make sure that at any given time I have 7 tabs displayed per page. Even if the total number of tabs is 10, I want to have 7 per page, and scroll to expose the other 3.
I can't find a property to control the number of tabs displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually what worked for me was to calculate the desired size of each cell to get the total amount of tabs that I needed per page and set `app:tabMaxWidth` inside `android.support.design.widget.TabLayout`

Comment: But how do you know the value to use, given that it is dependent upon screen resolution and stuff? I can see changing this dynamically (if there were APIs for that), but in a layout resource, I don't see how we can do this.