# How Can We Configure TabLayout For a Fixed Visible Number of Scrollable Tabs?

Tags: android, material-components-android

In a project, we are using the Material Design Components' `TabLayout` with a `ViewPager`. There are 14 tabs, and we want 7 of those tabs to be visible at a time in the `TabLayout`. The tab content is narrow enough that we are sure that 7 will not be too many, and the design team wants a consistent number of tabs showing up regardless of screen width (tabs represent days of the week).

None of the pre-defined tab modes seem to match this:

- `MODE_FIXED` and `MODE_AUTO` control the number of visible tabs... by showing all of them
- `MODE_SCROLLABLE` allows the tabs to scroll... but then we do not have control over the number of visible tabs

Is there a way of accomplishing this that does not involve non-maintainable hacks, such as using reflection to tinker with `tabPaddingStart` at runtime, or iterating over the tab widgets and adjusting their `LayoutParams`?

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57179855/115145), but the explanation is lacking — in particular, it is unclear how to use `app:tabMaxWidth` for what should be a dynamic value at runtime. Also, that question is about the older Design Support Library, which may differ somewhat with MDC's implementation.

Comment: There's a `tabMinWidth` XML attribute for `TabLayout`, at least in `material:1.1.0-beta01`. You could combine it with a custom tab view (`Tab.setCustomView(View)`). You'd have to know the desired width at tab creation time, or iterate through tabs and update each view later.

Comment: @EugenPechanec: I do not see how to use `tabMinWidth` at runtime, though. We do not know what 1/7th of the screen width is at compile time (at least as a `dp` dimension).

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I'd set `tabMinWidth` to zero. Then my custom views in tabs will have legroom to be as small as they want. One of the issues is that the default minimum width for scrollable tabs was 72dp. So step 1, override that to zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There several ways to show a fixed number of tabs irrespective of screen width that could work, but the desired functionality is really locked down. Most notably, if *getTabMinWidth()* in *TabLayout* were not private,  an easy solution would be to override that method in a custom *TabLayout* view.

The following is along that lines of, and maybe exactly, what Eugen Pechanec suggested in a comment above which involves a custom view for the tabs.

First the base layout.

**activity_main.xml**

`tabMinWidth`, `tabPaddingEnd` and `tabPaddingStart` are all set to `0dp`.  `tabMinWidth` has a default value that is probably too large for our needs. The padding could be set to other than zero, but I would rather deal with that in the custom views for the tabs.

Nothing really happens with the *ViewPager*.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:tabMinWidth="0dp"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"
            app:tabPaddingStart="0dp" />
    </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

**custom_tab.xml**

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Tab x"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2" />

<!--    If an icon is needed. -->
<!--    <ImageView-->
<!--        android:id="@android:id/icon"-->
<!--        android:layout_width="48dp"-->
<!--        android:layout_height="48dp"-->
<!--        android:scaleType="centerCrop"-->
<!--        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />-->
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

Tabs are loaded into the *TabLayout* one-by-one setting the custom views as we go. The minimum width of the custom views is set to 1/7 of the width of the *TabLayout*. Setting the minimum width suffices since it is given that the width needed will always be less than or equal to 1/7 of the total width.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val tabLayout = findViewById<TabLayout>(R.id.tabs)
        tabLayout.doOnLayout {
            val tabWidth = tabLayout.width / 7
            for (i in 1..14) {
                tabLayout.newTab().run {
                    setCustomView(R.layout.custom_tab)
                    customView?.minimumWidth = tabWidth
                    setText("Tab $i")
                    tabLayout.addTab(this)
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

If custom tabs are used anyway, I think that this is a reasonable solution. However, it is little better (IMO) than iterating over the *TabLayout* children and setting widths.

Finally, a couple of pictures:

[image: Portrait Orientation]

[image: Landscape Orientation]

Comment: This is basically what we had gone with. Many thanks for the detailed writeup!

Comment: Make the LinearLayout wrap height and width and put a lil padding so that the title wont stick to top. Depending on space between tabs you need, you can adjust the padding.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the same and I investigated the problem with the special attention. Spoiler: I failed - currently what you want to achieve is not possible via stock `TabLayout` and clean Android way.

There are hacks though)

- The most adequate one is to use library that allows that - for example [this](https://github.com/H07000223/FlycoTabLayout)
- Although you mentioned it and do not wan't to do it - iterating `TabLayout` children changing their `LayoutParams` is the next by adequacy way to do it. This method utilizes the public methods Android provides and does not require usage of some not very good techniques. Speaking of which...

### *Reflection start

- Change `tabPaddingStart` or `requestedTabMinWidth` along with `requestedTabMaxWidth`. It is bad. I won't even start why. It is the most inadequate one way in this list. It is still a way to fix it though.
- This one is the combination of clean Android way and `TabLayout` parameters `app:tabMaxWidth` and `app:tabMinWidth` and reflection. The reflection is a bit different in this case - it is almost normal(as much as a reflection can be). I propose to create an `integer` android resource in `integers.xml` called `tabWidth` or something (I'm sure you already know where I am going) and on application start you replace it via reflection with the value of your `screenWidth` divided by 7(or less depending on your paddings).

### *Reflection finish

- There is one more way and it is Android clean but quite inadequate nevertheless. You can use a combination of `ViewPagers` and/or fragments. The easiest one is a `ViewPager` of two `ViewPager`s and two `TabLayout`s each with 7 pages and 7 tabs accordingly. You might need to adjust gestures handler though. And there can be many more combinations.

I will not include a way of you writing the `TabLayout` by yourself with help of `RecyclerView` and `SnapHelper` because it always is an option to write something by yourself in Android... and waste tremendous amount of time.

I know that it is not an answer. Moreover it is rather list of how NOT to do stuff in Android but sometimes we need to choose the dark side...

Hope it helps though.